# AngularJS Add template(ng-view) without redirect to new page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I cannot realized my single page. I want add template page without redirect to new page.
My index.html file:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <head> 
      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script> 
      <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">About</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Contact</a>
         I want show contact and about information under this links but I see this at new page

        <ng-view> </ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js file  with routing configuration

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [ 'ngRoute']);

app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'dialogManager/page-home.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {}
    })
    // about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'dialogManager/page-about.html',
         controller: function ($scope) {}
    })
    // contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'dialogManager/page-contact.html',
         controller: function ($scope) {}
    });
} ]);
```

My page-contact.html

```
<!-- page-contact.html -->

<h2>Contact</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using ng-include instead.

As per angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

ngView is a directive that complements the $route service by including the rendered template of the current route into the main layout (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route service.

Maybe ng-view is not what you need.